# Child element being cut off in scrollable parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`context > div` is being cut off by its parent at the top and left. In my example below, I have a static width and height set for this element. But, javascript will dynamically determine those values in the future which is why I chose the absolute position route. I need the element to always be centered in the parent with width and height dynamic. I need scrollbars only on the parent and not the body. If there is another way to do this without an absolute position, I'd be more than happy to take a new direction.

Here is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/dominick/pen/PodOdbb

You can see when scrolling the parent all the way to the top, or all the way left, part of the child is cut off.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, I am not sure I understand the question.  I don't really see anything being cutoff unnecessarily in your codepen and honestly the layout looks pretty good to me.  My answers below are just alternative ways to horizontally center your content, which it seems like you might also be asking?  But if not, can you clarify which content is being "cut off".

Comment: It's nothing major, but you'll notice the black borders are cut off on the top and left. The parent is not scrolling to the full width/height of the child. This will turn out to be a big issue in the app I'm developing as it needs to be pixel perfect. Essentially, the element will be zoomed in and out. It works fine until I center it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Per OP's updated requirements, I think this is the way to go:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
header {
  background: red;
  height:80px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
main {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
.left {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width:300px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-header {
  background: #999999;
  margin: 10px;
}
.context {
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.context > div {
  height: 20px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  border:2px solid #000;
  margin: auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is main header
</header>
<main>
  <div class='left'>
    left panel
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
    <div class='context'>
      <div>
        Super long div
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

### END EDIT

You can accomplish this without `position: absolute` in a number of ways.  One is with `margin: 0px auto`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
header {
  background: red;
  height:80px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
main {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
.left {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width:300px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-header {
  background: #999999;
  margin: 10px;
}
.context {
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.context > div {
  height: 20px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  border:2px solid #000;
  margin: auto auto;
 
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is main header
</header>
<main>
  <div class='left'>
    left panel
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
    <div class='context'>
      <div>
        Super long div
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Another could be a centered `flexbox` on your containing element:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
header {
  background: red;
  height:80px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
main {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
.left {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width:300px;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sub-header {
  background: #999999;
  margin: 10px;
}
.context {
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.context > div {
  height: 20px;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  border:2px solid #000;
  margin: auto 0px;
 
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is main header
</header>
<main>
  <div class='left'>
    left panel
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
    <div class='context'>
      <div>
        Super long div
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class='sub-header'>
      This is sub header
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I would also encourage you to Google around for other StackOverflow questions asking the same thing - variations of "how can I center this div" are asked many times per day.

Comment: In both of those examples, the scroll is on the body and not the parent element.

Comment: Ah got it.  Updated to add `height: calc(100vh - 80px)` to your `<main>` element

Comment: This works great. However, I need the element centered both horizontally and vertically in the parent. When adding align-items: center; in the parent, I run into the clipping issue again :(

Comment: I don't follow.  Is there another, separate use case where "super long div" is actually really small and doesn't cause a scrollbar at all?

Comment: Yes, in the end "super long div" will be an element that is zoomed in and out in the UI. When a user zooms in and out it will change the width and height of the element. Transform scale will not work in my use case. If you visit canva.com and use their design editor, their zoom in / out feature is similar to what I'm going for.

Comment: Well then you can also use an auto-margin on the top and bottom of your div to center it vertically when it doesn't fill the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

After having removed this line:

```css
.context > div {
  height: 900px;
  width:1200px;
  position: absolute;
  background:#ccc;
  border:2px solid #000;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
/*  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) REMOVED LINE */
}
```

everything was working fine for me. Try setting the margin of this element if you wants to obtain a space all around it.